# how to launch apps in the visionos sim

Tags: visionos

I have built my hello world app and it runs in the simulator. I can also get the Home Screen with my icon and the icon of the other included apps in the sim. However, I cannot launch any apps in the sim, neither my app nor the included ones.

The icons pop a bit when the mouse goes over them, but do not respond to clicks.

Any suggestions? TIA!

Answer (score 3):

You need to be in `interact` mode in order to tap on elements. There's a UI in the bottom right of the simulator or Xcode preview that changes between states. The far left one (with the pointer) is the one you need.

[image: Vision interaction state icons]